# Angular2 Using Pipes in Component.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-pipe

I'm learning Angular2 and I want to format a number adding thousand comma separator. As far as I have read this can be done using Pipes, the thing is that I want to format the number programmatically in the js file not in html (doing like var | number).

First of all I've realized there is no NumberPipe standalone pipe that I can work with (correct me if I'm wrong) the most similar one is CurrencyPipe in @angular2/common. So I have something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent {
    public myNumber = 1000;

    constructor(private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) {    
        var formatted = this.currencyPipe().transform(this.myNumber, 'MXN', true); // Is this correct?
    }

}
```

But it throws me the following error:
    **Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for CurrencyPipe! ; Zone: angular ;...**

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: why not use it like `{{ myNumber | currency:'USD':true }}`

Comment: @MrNew Because I'm retrieving data from an API a using it to draw a Chart.js chart... No HTML here, so I can't use it {{myNumber | currency}}, I need to format the data programatically.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First thing: you need to declare your pipe - add it to the NgModule `declarations` section:

```
declarations: [CurrencyPipe]
```

Second thing: pipes are not injectables, so you can't take its instance by using Angular dependency injection system. You need to create new instance of this pipe manually, like:

```
var formatted = (new CurrencyPipe()).transform(this.myNumber, 'MXN', true);
```

Comment: This works... but I had to pass a locale id string as a parameter to CurrencyPipe when creating the instance like this: return new CurrencyPipe('es-MX').transform(this.myNumber, 'MXN', true);

Comment: @Daniel Kucal - You suggested to 'provide' the pipe, by adding it to providers array. This looks confusing, as what I have learnt so far only services are provided, Components, Pipes and Directives must be 'Imported' into 'Imports' array.

Do I miss something here?

Comment: Hi @DeepakPathak, thanks for your question, the instruction here was outdated and causing an error. In previous Angular version it was also working with pipe added to **component's** (that's important) providers, I've updated the answer. Components, pipes and directives should be placed in `declarations`. `imports` is for importing one NgModule into another.

Comment: @DanielKucal - Appreciate your response and update. Happy Coding!

Comment: There is new format for the display parameter as per [this](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe) document. TLDR: a boolean value is deprecated, use one of the string values instead.

Answer (score 1):

This actually works in an @Injectable display utility service with even less fuss than the previous answer involving modules.  I imported my data model (below) and the pipe, then simply added the function.  So, if you can't use the pipe directly in markup, use this trick!

```
export interface MoneyDTO extends SerializableDTO, JsonModelObjectDTO {
  value?: string;
  currency?: string;
}

import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';

formatMoney(money: MoneyDTO): string {
  const cp: CurrencyPipe = new CurrencyPipe('en-US');

  return money && money.value ? cp.transform(money.value, money.currency || 'USD', 'symbol') : null;
}
```