# Angular Currency pipe in component

Tags: angular, currency, angular-pipe

I'm trying to use this currency pipe in component.ts file.But doesn't produce same results.

```
{{ money |currency: 'EUR': 'symbol' : '' : locale}}
this.currencyPipe.transform(money, 'EUR', '', true);
```

Comment: please have a look https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

Comment: why are you sending true as locale?

Comment: Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840265/angular2-using-pipes-in-component-js

Answer (score 11):

```
//add currency pipe to your constructor in x.ts
private currencyPipe:CurrencyPipe
//add to your providers in app.module or to your child module if you have nested routes.

providers: [CurrencyPipe],

//use the pipe in x.ts as;
let some_money = 3000
let me_converted = this.currencyPipe.transform(some_money, 'Ksh.');
console.log(me_converted); //Ksh.3,000.00
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
locale: String;
digitInfo: String
this.currencyPipe.transform(money, 'EUR', 'symbol', digitInfo, locale);
```